# Add to cart adding first item

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a simple cart where I can add items on the fly and it update via AJAX. Issue being I am pulling my items from the database but when I click 'add to cart' it populates the cart but with the first item only so no matter which one I click it adds item 1.

I am looping through a result and getting the row:

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

    echo '
    <div class="items" id="item">
    <a href="doc_view.php?prod_id='.$row["prod_id"].'"> '.$row["prod_name"]. '</a>';

    echo "
    <div class='product_display'>
    <p><img src='../admin/uploads/".$row['file_upload']."'></p>";    


   echo"
    <input type='button' value='Add To CART' onclick='cart(\"item\");' "; 

    echo'
    <p>Price - '.$row["prod_price"]. '</p>
    <input type="hidden" id="item_name" value="'.$row["prod_name"]. '">
    <input type="hidden" id="item_price" value="'.$row["prod_price"]. '">';?>

    <?php echo'
    </div>
    </div>
    ';


    }
```

The echo's really need cleaning up but they confuse me so much!

I am using a little bit of JS to do the AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'store_items.php',
    data:{
      total_cart_items:"totalitems"
    },
    success:function(response) {
      document.getElementById("total_items").value=response;
    }
  });

});
```

And my JS does the rest:

```
    function cart(id)
    {
    var ele=document.getElementById(id);
    var img_src=ele.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
    var name=document.getElementById(id+"_name").value;
    var price=document.getElementById(id+"_price").value;

    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'store_items.php',
        data:{
          item_src:img_src,
          item_name:name,
          item_price:price
        },
        success:function(response) {
          document.getElementById("total_items").value=response;
        }
      });

    }

    function show_cart()
    {
      $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:'store_items.php',
      data:{
        showcart:"cart"
      },
      success:function(response) {
        document.getElementById("mycart").innerHTML=response;
        $("#mycart").slideToggle();
      }
     });

    }
```

I thought I would share it all so you can see - but the main issue is the fact it just adds item 1 form the list no matter which one you click on - I am getting no errors and the console is giving me nothing?

Comment: Because you are trying to pass an array. It is possible to pass array values using `class` but not for `id` tags.

Comment: @LoganWayne Could you show me a small example of what you mean? I am still really struggling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using the same `id` for all your items. IDs should only be used once per page, and in cases where you are using it multiple times, `document.getElementById(id)` will only get the first one that it finds which is why you keep on getting the first item in the list only.

You can give each item different `id`s and pass that id to the `cart` function. Or to make things simplier, use event delegation (since you're already using jQuery) to listen for clicks on the Add To Cart button so that you don't have to use the `onclick` attribute anymore. You can do it like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'ADDTOCARTBUTTONSELECTOR', function() {
    var element = $(this).closest('.items');
    var image = element.find('img')[0].src;
    var name = element.find('NAMESELECTOR').val();
    var price=document.find('PRICESELECTOR').val();

    // the ajax part follows here
});
```

The `ADDTOCARTBUTTONSELECTOR`, `NAMESELECTOR`, and `PRICESELECTOR` are just placeholders to the actual selectors to those elements, and just replace them appropriately to select the proper elements.

Comment: I am a little confused - so am I adding this to my current JS?

Comment: @phpcoder yeah, you replace your `cart` function with this one, although the contents are just kinda the same.